# Приемлемо ли выражение "удача всех моих лет"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Удача всех моих лет............*

Answer (score 4):

Лучше сказать: **удача всей моей жизни**.

Например:

Удача может покинуть вас, синьор Эудженио! ― Музыка ― удача всей моей жизни. ― Но и постоянная поддержка кое-что в жизни музыкальной значит! [Борис Евсеев. Евстигней // «Октябрь», 2010]

Answer (score 1):

> > Правильно ли сказано выражение

Неправильно сказан вопрос... Да и выражение не кажется мне удачным.